# TypeError: this.state.blog.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to display the info of a particular element by getting data from database Mongodb atlas when clicked on it and I'm getting this error. Any one pls help me on this. Below is my code. I checked with both console.log typeof response.data and response.data

```
For console.log(response.data); it returns 

{_id: "5f116b93de82187214265ea2", username: "Bradd Fox", place: "Chick N' Lamb", dish: "Chicken WIngs", description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing a…ldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.", …}
createdAt: "2020-07-17T09:12:51.270Z"
description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
dish: "Chicken WIngs"
image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562967914-608f82629710?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1052&q=80"
place: "Chick N' Lamb"
rating: 4
updatedAt: "2020-07-17T09:12:51.270Z"
username: "Bradd Fox"
__v: 0
_id: "5f116b93de82187214265ea2"
__proto__: Object

console.log(typeof response.data); returns an object.

import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "../../components/Header/Header";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import BlogInfo from "../../components/BlogInfo/BlogInfo";

class Blog extends Component {
  state = {
    blog: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/blogs/" + this.props.match.params.id)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          blog: response.data,
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      });
  }

  render() {
    let blogInfo = this.state.blog.map((data) => {
      return (
        <BlogInfo
          key={data._id}
          id={data._id}
          Name={data.username}
          Place={data.place}
          Dish={data.dish}
          Description={data.description}
          Image={data.image}
          Rating={data.rating}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Container className="my-4">{blogInfo}</Container>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Blog;
```

Comment: Could you change the console.log in the `.then()` to `console.log(response.data)` and edit your question to include what it prints out? The API is probably returning something that's not an array.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `response.data`?

Comment: The error `this.state.blog.map is not function` will usually occur when `this.state.blog` is not an **array**. Try loggin the value of `response.data` and see if you get the correct value.

Comment: I have edited my question with both console.log outputs. They both return object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, this error means that `this.state.blog` is not an array. Try to modify your code like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
axios
  .get("http://localhost:3000/blogs/" + this.props.match.params.id)
  .then((response) => {
    let array_response = [response.data];
    this.setState({
      blog: array_response,
    });
    console.log(this.state.blog);
  });
 }
```

Comment: I have edited my question with both console.log outputs. They both return object

Comment: Oh ok, so your `blog` object infact is a JSON object. Well, you cannot use a `map` function on JSON object. `map` is for array of JOSN object. I have updated my answer. What do you think?

Comment: No problem. You can click the checkmark on the left of my answer if you think this answer helped you. Have a nice day :)